# How modify the request headers using safari extension

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

I am developing a safari extension which will modify the http request headers.
I am able to modify the request headers in chrome and firefox extensions but not in safari extension.
In chrome there is [webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) API to modify the request header. 
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function (details));

In firefox by using the "http-on-examine-response" http Request Observer
Any help or clues are mostly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no way for you to do that with Safari. You can however inject content scripts and listen to HTML events and block your pages or use the beforeNavigate events. Safari's extension API is pretty limited with what you can and cannot do. Sorry :(.